# Angular 2: Sharing attributes between components

Tags: angular

I'm having some trouble getting my app.component.html file to have access to attributes from some child components. I have looked at other examples, but haven't gotten anything to work for me. I'm using the latest 2.0.0 version. Here is a look at some of my code:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SellingComponent } from './selling.component';
import { GrowingComponent } from './growing.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'Areas/Plan/app/app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['Areas/Plan/app/app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="sub-nav-dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle sub-nav-dropdown-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        {{subnav}}
        <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-nav-options" id="growSellNav">
        <li>
            <a routerLink="/Plan/Production/Selling" routerLinkActive="active" id="selling" class="">Selling</a> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <a routerLink="/Plan/Production/Growing" routerLinkActive="active" id="growing" class="">Growing</a> 
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The router outlet will spit out the html from growing.component.html and selling.component.html, depending on which option in the dropdown you select. In growing.component.ts and selling.component.ts, I have a `subnav` attribute that I want displayed where `{{subnav}}` is in the app.component.html file, but I can't get it to work. Here is the code from those other components:

```
export class GrowingComponent implements OnInit {
    public subnav = 'Growing';

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('initializing GrowingComponent');
    }
}

export class SellingComponent implements OnInit {
    public subnav = 'selling';

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('initializing SellingComponent');
    }
}
```

Comment: Put `subnav` in a shared service.  [Use observables](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) or put `subnav` inside an object in the service -- e.g., `mySharedObj = { subnav:  value };` -- then get a reference to the object in AppComponent -- this.sharedObj = MyService.getSharedObj();` -- and use `{{sharedObj.subnav}}` in your view.

Comment: Is getSharedObj() a function I will need to create, or will I need to import something to be able to use that?

Comment: It is a method you would create on your service.  You'll need to import the service into all three components, and inject it into all three component constructors.  Then you can call public methods on the service.

Comment: If you need change notification, consider making mySharedObj an Rx Subject: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject then subscribe in AppComponent, and publish/next in child components.

Comment: See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

Make a new service for sending data between components.

```
component.interaction.service.ts

getSubNav = new Subject();
getSubNav$ = this.getSubNav.asObservable();
sendSubnav(text:string){
this.getSubNav.next(text);
}

app.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { SellingComponent } from './selling.component';
import { GrowingComponent } from './growing.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'Areas/Plan/app/app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['Areas/Plan/app/app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

subnav:string ="";
subscription:Subscription;

constructor(private ciService:ComponentService){}

ngOnInit(){}
  this.subscription = this.ciService.getSubnav$
    .subscribe((res:string) => this.subnav = res);
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  if(this.subscription){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And then,

```
export class GrowingComponent implements OnInit {
    public subnav = 'Growing';
    constructor(private ciService: ComponentService){}
    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('initializing GrowingComponent');
        this.ciService.sendSubnav(this.subnav);
    }
}

export class SellingComponent implements OnInit {
    public subnav = 'selling';
    constructor(private ciService: ComponentService){}
    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('initializing SellingComponent');
        this.ciService.sendSubnav(this.subnav);
    }
}
```